# Windows Server 2008 - Is there a way to globally release a third-party software install/update?

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2008, deployment

We are running MS Small Business Server 2008, and there are a few programs that we would like to have installed on all client computers. Is there a way to install this software on all machines without manually going to each computer?  Obviously this can be done with windows updates and such, but we're hoping for more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy software centrally through:

- GPO
- Login script (depends if users are admin / using runas)
- Use a true software deployment, like Microsoft SCCM (replace MS SMS)
- housemade script that copy the exe/msi to remote targets and launch them remotely in silent mode. PowerShell v2 enable some good points to that

Example: deploy office 2007 through GPO: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179214.aspx

The more industrial way is SCCM but it cost money (but save you time, tradeoff)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the software. You can do a lot with [SCCM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/en/us/default.aspx) if you have the resources.

Answer (score 0):

With SBS I assume that you're a reasonably small environment, so look into Group Policy based software deployment as a first step.  If your needs exceed the capabilities of that method, and you're not able to structure things within it's limitations, then it's time to go further to something like SCCM.

Clickies:

- http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Deploy-Applications.html
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739305(WS.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782727(WS.10).aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

Answer (score 0):

For your application distribution or update you can build .msi packets using special programs (For example Advanced Installer, MSIFactory and etc) and then create appropriate group policy to deploy them.